# GDBとLLDBの違い

Tags: gdb

[GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/)と[LLDB](http://lldb.llvm.org/)の違いは何でしょうか。
特にGDBに出来てLLDBに出来ないこと、またはその逆について知りたいです。

Answer (score 4):

lldb つかってないので期待された答えになってないかもしれないすが・・・

gdb (つか gcc もですが) は古くからあるのに対して
lldb (llvm/clang) は新しいです。

lldb/clang は古い CPU をサポートしていません。
また現状、組み込み系 CPU に対するサポートも薄いようです。
ウチの hpux で使っている pa-risc2.0 CPU 向けバイナリを作るには gcc/gdb が必要です。
SH/RX/MN103 等の組み込み CPU 向けバイナリも gcc/gdb でないと作れません。

Answer (score 4):

目的別にgdbコマンドとlldbコマンドを比較しているページ "[LLDB to GDB Command Map](http://lldb.llvm.org/lldb-gdb.html)" があります。特にlldbだと出来てgdbだと直接対応するコマンドが無い（たぶん）ものが分かり易いと思います。

gdbの方が有利なケースとしては、774RRさん回答にもあるように多種多様なCPUアーキテクチャサポートが挙げられると思います。あとはgdbの方が歴史が古いので、コマンド体系に慣れている人や情報が多い点もある気はします。